# how to get all the data to CSV from memorystream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-csv, memorystream, csvhelper

Below is my method to export data to CSV.

```
public MemoryStream ExportToCsv(string jsonData, HttpResponseBase response, string fileName)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        try
        {
            String s = JsonToCsv(jsonData, ",");
            writer.Write(s);
            stream.Position = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clsErrorHandling.WriteLog("CSVExport", "GenerateStreamFromString", ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            response.Clear();
            response.Buffer = true;
            response.ContentType = "application/csv";
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "");
            response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
        }

        return stream;
    }
}

#region Private CSV Block

private String JsonToCsv(string jsonData, string delimiter)
{
    try
    {
        using (StringWriter swObj = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(swObj))
            {
                csv.Configuration.SkipEmptyRecords = true;
                csv.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
                csv.Configuration.Delimiter = delimiter;

                using (var dt = jsonStringToTable(jsonData))
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        csv.WriteField(col.ColumnName);
                    }
                    csv.NextRecord();

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                        {
                            csv.WriteField(row[i]);
                        }
                        csv.NextRecord();
                    }
                }

            }
            return swObj.ToString();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        clsErrorHandling.WriteLog("CSVExportHandler", "JsonToCsv", ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}

private DataTable jsonStringToTable(string jsonContent)
{
    DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonContent);
    return dt;
}

#endregion
```

If the number of records is less than 100.Then no issue. But when the data is 100 or 150+ , last 15-20records are not written to the csv file.

Suppose if the number of records is 175, then I get in csv some around 163.
If the number of records is 150 then I get in csv  arounf 131 & so on.

What could be the causing this ? How should I handle this?

Comment: Why did you comment out writer.Flush() and writer.Close() ? This shloud flush internal buffers of StreamWriter to MemoryStream and solve your problem.

Comment: @Ňuf, I just checked with Uncommenting them but still same issue.

Comment: So there is probably one more problem similar to this, although I don't see it. Could you check whether swObj.ToString() returns all records? This should give us a hint whether problem is in ExportToCsv() or JsonToCsv().

Comment: BTW you can convert string to byte array much easier with System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonToCsv(jsonData, ",")), without need for StreamWriter or MemoryStream, thus avoiding potential problem with StreamWriter's buffering.

Comment: @Ňuf. :) I checked some hours back on   swObj.ToString() . It has the right number of records

Comment: This reduces possible source of problem to StreamWriter, MemoryStream and HttpResponseBase in ConvertToCsv() method. Where exactly are you missing your records, is it in HttpResponse or in MemoryStream returned from ConvertToCsv method? Because now I realized that MemoryStream returned from ConvertToCsv() method is Disposed - although this might not be problem you are looking for, it is at least weird to return disposed object as result of function.

Comment: @Ňuf. Please have a look at the ans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number small updates in my `public` method fixed my issue.

```
public MemoryStream ExportToCsv(string jsonData, HttpResponseBase response, string fileName)
{
       using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            try
            {
                response.Clear();
                response.Buffer = true;
                response.ContentType = "application/csv";
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "");
                String s = JsonToCsv(jsonData, ",");
                writer.Write(s);
                writer.Flush();

                stream.Position = 0;
                response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                writer.Close();
            }
    return stream;
}
```

}

Hope this helps :)